# Как сделать в Symfony 4 UNIQUE под вум полям в Mysql

Tags: doctrine2, symfony4, php7.2

Суть задачи:
Нужно на уровне БД сделать проверку на уникальность пары (двух полей)

```
id  |fild1  |fild2 |
----|------|-------|
1   |A     |B      | <- OK
2   |D     |B      | <- OK
3   |A     |A      | <- OK
4   |A     |A      | <- ERR - уже есть такая пара A A 
5   |B     |A      | <- OK
```

Вообщем нужно проверять fild1 и fild2 на уникальность ВМЕСТЕ а не по отдельности. 
Было загуглено что в мускуле за это отвечает UNIQUE 
Я работаю с Symfony 4 + Doctrine 
Создаю сущьность и пытаюсь сделать такую проверк

```
/**
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"fild1"}, groups={"groups1"})
 * @UniqueEntity(fields={"fild2"}, groups={"groups1"})
 */
class superClass
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id()
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue()
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="fild1", unique=true )
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\fild1")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false,referencedColumnName="code")
     */
    private $fild1;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(name="fild2", unique=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\fild2")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false,referencedColumnName="code")
     */
    private $fild2;
```

И при миграции что то идет не так, он генерирует UNIQUE

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8660A37E5569975D ON currency_links (fild1)
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX UNIQ_8660A37E8105B598 ON currency_links (fild2)
```

Он делает так что на каждое поле должно быть только одно уникальное значение, соответсвенно у меня на записи 2 появляется ошибка потому что **B** в fild2 есть выше, мне кажется он просто игнорирует groups

Подскажите как написать в Entity что бы проверка шла на уникальность fild1+fild2 а не на каждое свое?

Дополнение:
Вообщем мне удалось сделать то что нужно на чистом sql

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ix` (`fild1`, `fild2`);
```

Но как это написать в Entity так и не понятно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="my_entity",
 *     uniqueConstraints={@ORM\UniqueConstraint(name="unique_map_idx", columns={"field1", "field2"})})
 * @package App\Entity\Complains
 */
class MyEntity 
{
    // 
}
```

> https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/annotations-reference.html#uniqueconstraint

Указывать надо имена полей, как они именованы в БД. Т.е. если поля `field1`, `field2` - это референсы на другие сущности, то следует указывать `field1_id`, `field2_id`

Comment: ДА НАКАНЕЦТА! - Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

См. [UniqueEntity](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/UniqueEntity.html), описание @UniqueEntity (тип - строка или массив строк) и пример в @errorPath.

```
@UniqueEntity(fields={"field1", "field2"}, groups={"group1"})
```

Comment: не помогло, не чего не изменилось

Comment: Он всеравно не правельно собирает зарпосы для миграции, мне удалось решить это на sql но как сделать это в Entity я незнаю

Comment: `ALTER TABLE table_name
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `ix` (`fild1`, `fild2`);`